# UICollectionView reload data not working when called in textFieldShouldEndEditing method of cell's textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionviewcell

I am using textfield in my custom cell. All the delegate methods of textfields are working fine. When the editing of textfield completes, I am saving changed data and updating datasource (i have checked and data is updated too) and then calling [collectionView reloadData] method but delegate methods of UICollectionView are not fired.

```
 **//Custom cell class textfield delegate method**
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
**//tableReload is existing class table view reload method**
   [self.delegate reloadCollectionView];
   return YES;

}

**//Method in another class
-(void)reloadCollectionView{
 [arrayForTable removeAllObjects];
[self saveData];
[collectionView reloadData];

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: will you please explain a little. Which method should be on main thread? Thanks.

Comment: I changed the method from textFieldShouldEndEditing: to textFieldDidEndEditing: and it is working now. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the method from **textFieldShouldEndEditing:** to **textFieldDidEndEditing:** and it is working now.